# Upcasting an `Arc<dyn Trait>` to an `Arc<dyn Any>`?

Tags: rust, casting, unsafe

Suppose I have a trait object of type `Asset`, which is stored in an `Arc`, and I want to convert it to an `Arc<dyn Any>` to facilitate later downcasting.

Is there any safe way to do this? I have tried this (unsafe) strategy using the [`as-any`](https://docs.rs/as-any/latest/as_any/) crate, but it seems to break the type information as I can't `downcast` the resulting `Arc<dyn Any>` to its base type:

```
    let res: Box<dyn Asset> = thing_that_returns_dyn_asset();
    let res: Arc<dyn Asset> = Arc::from(res);

    // Unsafe: Cast an Arc<dyn Asset> to an Arc<dyn Any>.
    let res : Arc<dyn Any> = unsafe {
         Arc::from_raw(Arc::into_raw(res).as_any())
    };
```

But it does not seem to work. I'm aware that there's a currently experimental feature to upcast objects, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: The unstable trait upcasting [does work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e20e1b89dfac144fc082b11c7987bf66), and it is the easiest way if you can use nightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a method that casts from `Arc<Asset>` to `Arc<dyn Any>`. Following `as-any`, we can do that in a custom trait and have a blanket implementation for it:

```rust
pub trait AsAnyArc {
    fn as_any_arc(self: Arc<Self>) -> Arc<dyn Any>;
}

impl<T: 'static> AsAnyArc for T {
    fn as_any_arc(self: Arc<Self>) -> Arc<dyn Any> { self }
}

pub trait Asset: AsAnyArc { ... }

let res: Box<dyn Asset> = thing_that_returns_dyn_asset();
let res: Arc<dyn Asset> = Arc::from(res);

let res: Arc<dyn Any> = res.as_any_arc();
```